# Angular controller function not running

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to make an HTTP GET to an API and I'm not getting anything back in the console log, so I'm assuming this function isn't running.

This is the jsfiddle I'm trying to recreate in my Angular app, which has the proper data structure:

http://jsfiddle.net/bgoldste/keam6q9o/

Here's **controller.js**

```
.controller('GamesCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    function GamesCtrl($scope, $http) {
        console.log("did this run");
        $http(
        {
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'https://www.kimonolabs.com/api/bzq274q4?apikey=JfagXh7xfxWsnWGzLAKpBIrTFwENcGY6',
            headers: {
                'authorization': 'Bearer xOZHZE4sit0Pe6VGqsOQn5jKPpA5QpG3'
            }
        }).
        success(function (data) {
            $scope.data = data['results']['collection1'];
        });
    }
})
```

And here's **games.html**

```
<ion-view title="Games" ng­controller="GamesCtrl">
  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item ng-repeat="row in data">
        {{row['property1']['src']}}
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

I'm not even seeing a network request in the console from that GET

Comment: There is not enough information given here for us to have any idea without asking 20 questions. You provided no information about status of request, data structure returned etc.

Comment: I just edited the question with a link to the jsfiddle I'm trying to reproduce http://jsfiddle.net/bgoldste/keam6q9o/

Comment: Correct, but my project locally is not bringing back data.

Comment: so what about status of request itself? Inspect it in your network tab. Use an error handler also

Comment: Make sure your url is correct and second thing if locally it is not working please check that it is not issue of firewall.

Comment: I don't even see it appearing in the network request. That's where I'm stumped.

Comment: did you forget to bootstrap angular?

Comment: Nope, angular is running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two nested function definitions - the second one won't even be called.  Try this instead:

```
.controller('GamesCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    console.log("did this run");
    $http(
    {
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https://www.kimonolabs.com/api/bzq274q4?apikey=JfagXh7xfxWsnWGzLAKpBIrTFwENcGY6',
        headers: {
            'authorization': 'Bearer xOZHZE4sit0Pe6VGqsOQn5jKPpA5QpG3'
        }
    }).
    success(function (data) {
        $scope.data = data['results']['collection1'];
    });

})
```